# Rails js-routes: get path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, js-routes

In my rails app I'm trying to make a transition link in my javascript file with help of [js-routes gem](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/)

```
$.get(Routes.pay_account_path(self.tour.ID(), {format: 'html'}), function () {
  return true;
});
```

This code seems correct, but there is no transition to path when I click on the button. In browser inspector network I see that `http://example.dev/account/38469212-6116-91B2-591C-91D30FBDD6B6/pay.html` response is OK